# How to get ICompilationUnit open after getting from PackageFragment? Java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Currently I am writing a plugin and one of its functions is to traverse packages and java files. I can grab the java file names but they all say that they are not open. Is there a way to open them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IComplilationUnit` has `IOpenable` as a superinterface. Call `open()` on the object.